# Algorithms for classification of very short text

Tags: nlp, transformer

I am to create a classification model for texts that typically have 3 to 4 words in them. I thought of using BERT and XLNet but not sure if they are the right choice for texts that short.

Are there any models(pretrained or otherwise) that specialise for classification of short text?

Comment: What kind of classification?

Comment: @spectre, multi-class classification. I have 26 categories that these short texts may fall under.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataset?